# ISE14.6 VHDL textio problem, about writing line at the output file

Tags: vhdl

while preparing for a project about digital circuit class, I have a question about reading lines from 'input.txt' to writing lines at 'output.txt'.
I was intend to copy the 'input.txt' lines to 'output.txt' lines. However, there was unintended integers at the 'output.txt'. My codes are below.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_TEXTIO.ALL;
use STD.TEXTIO.ALL;

entity TOP_Xray_cnn is
    port( clk: in std_logic);
end TOP_Xray_cnn;

architecture Behavioral of TOP_Xray_cnn is
begin

process(clk)
  file inFile : text open read_mode is "input.txt";
  file outFile: text open write_mode is "output.txt";
        
  variable line_in : line;
  variable line_out : line;
  variable data_in : integer;
  variable data_out : integer;      

begin

 if rising_edge(clk) then

 while not(endfile(inFile)) loop
   readline(inFile, line_in);
   read(line_in, data_in);  

   data_out := data_in + 1; 
   write(line_out, data_out);
   writeline(outFile, line_out);
 end loop;
 end if;
 file_close(inFile);
 file_close(outFile);

end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Input.txt

```
1                               
2                               
3                               
4                               
5
```

output.txt

```
22
3
4
5
6
```

what happen to the first row of output.txt file?
why are there two '2' which  I intend one '2' ??

Comment: Two issues. ISE 14.6 ISim isn't VHDL standard compliant here (using file pointers of closed files) and because all non-postponed processes in a design model execute until suspended the files are closed (outside the if statement with the condition rising_edge(clk)).  They won't be open on the rising_edge and you should get an error for calling endfile for a file that isn't opened. Use a better simulator and correct your code. Supply a [mcve] (here providing a rising_edge on clk). Your output.txt shown could not have come from executing this code in a compliant implementation.